# Google app engine datastore: Summing the values stored inside a single column

Tags: google-app-engine

I have a database named 'Employee' in my application:

```
class Employee(db.Model):
    id = db.IntegerProperty(required = True)
    name = db.StringProperty(required = True)
    role = db.StringProperty()
    date_of_joining = db.StringProperty()
    salary = db.IntegerProperty()
    current_task = db.TextProperty()
    percentage_task = db.FloatProperty()
```

Now, how could I sum the salary of all the employees whose entries are stored in the 'Employee' database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's what you currently have, you'd have to get the whole list of 'Employee' and then iterate through them to get a running total, as the datastore doesn't natively support aggregation functions.

Something like :

```
employees = db.Query(Employee, projection=('salary'))
for employee in employees:
    salarySum += employee.salary
```

On the other hand, if the salary sum is something you need relatively often, it might be a better idea to keep a counter totaling the salaries, updating it at the same time you update salaries (if the updates are frequent, you might need to look into [sharding counters](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/sharding_counters) to make sure you don't run into contention problems).